# How to rotate a 3D graphed cone?

Tags: geometry

I am currently doing an assignment on 3D graphing and using the Grapher app on Mac I can graph various shapes and lines. I graphed a cone with a circular base using the equation $c^2((x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2) = r^2(z-z_1)^2$. What modifications do I need to make to the equation to add a rotation about the 3 principal axes or any other line?

Edit: I understand my initial question may not have been clear enough, however, after some additional research I found an answer to my question. If there is a point or line that I wish to rotate about the origin, I can use a rotation matrix ([2D Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions)). I discovered there are matrices that allow for similar rotation about the coordinate axes in 3D ([3D Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions)).

Comment: FYI: it's a principAL axis, not principle. Also: this *seems* to be a question about the "grapher" app rather than mathematics. Perhaps you could illustrate with a simpler example (i.e.,"if I have a circle, like ..., then I can modify the equation like this: ... , to include a translation") so that we know what it is you're hoping to see. [You can edit your question by clicking on the gray "edit" just below the question itself to include such amplifications.]

Comment: I've changed principle, thank you for that one. I answered my question after further research which I've added to the post itself. Although I felt it was clear that the question was addressing the equation I'll be sure to be clearer with future questions.

Comment: @SukhyGills Since you've found a solution to your problem, could you post it as an answer here so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue? You are, in fact, allowed to [answer your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)!